# Trying to go to a file inside code by clicking in Laravel VS Code

Tags: laravel-5, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.33.1

I am trying to go to a file in my code by doing a `CTRL + Click` but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Visiting a file via click]

As you may see, I would like to visit the AuthenticatesUsers file somewhere in my project. What is the click shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 14):

To do that you need to install the [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client). after installing let PHP Intelephense to scan the project and  `Ctrl + click` on your class which will allow you go to the definition. if `Ctrl + click` didn't work try `Alt + click`

Comment: When you say go to definition, do you mean open the file itself or just plain description ?

Comment: `Ctrl + click` will open the file. You could also press `Alt + F12` to peek the definition if you don't need to open it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Laravel Goto](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=absszero.vscode-laravel-goto) Extension in VS Code.

By Hovering you can go to

- Go to Blade Template files (EX. hello.blade.php)
- Go to Blade Component files (EX. )
- Go to Controller and highlight method (EX.
  \Namespace\Controller.php@Method)
- Go to Static files (EX. hello.js)
- Go to Config files and highlight option (EX. config\app.php)
- Go to Language files (EX. resources/lang/en/messages.php )
- Go to .env and highlight option

Answer (score 2):

Download the VSC extension [Laravel goto view](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codingyu.laravel-goto-view)

Once downloaded, enable the extension and press `Ctrl + click` to navigate to the desire file as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Is it works for Controller `Route::get('/', [PostController::class,'index'])->name('home');` for example when i click on `PostController` it should go to that controller ??